# Set partitions on existing index in Dask dataframe

Tags: dask

If I have an already indexed Dask dataframe with

```
>>> A.divisions
(None, None)
>>> A.npartitions
1
```

and I want to set the divisions, so far I'm doing

```
A.reset_index().set_index("index", divisions=sorted(divisions))
```

because `A.repartition(divisions=sorted(divisions))` complains "left side of old and new divisions are different". Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of `dask.__version__ == '0.16.0'` if you happen to know the divisions of an existing dataframe you can assign them directly.

```
A.divisions = tuple(divisions)
```